# JS: Extending the size of one div affects the size of all divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing a very simple exercise with divs creating cards with a button as a switch to show or hide an answer. I wanted to re-use the code of the first card to make all the divs I wanted with the same behaviour.

Here's the script and the link with the exercise so it's easier to see:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="card">
  <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Sv1a28N.png" alt="manzana" /></div>
  <div class="card-title">Apple</div>
  <button class="card-button">Show</button>
  <div class="card-answer">Manzana</div>
</div>
```

And the script

```
var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
  for (var cardIndex in cards) {
    var button = cards[cardIndex].querySelector('.card-button');
      button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        var currentButton = event.target;
        var currentCard = currentButton.parentNode;
        var currentAnswer = currentCard.querySelector('.card-answer');
    
        if (currentButton.innerHTML == 'Show') {
            currentAnswer.style.display = "block";
            currentButton.innerHTML = 'Hide';
        } else if (currentButton.innerHTML == 'Hide')
        {
            currentAnswer.style.display = 'None';
            currentButton.innerHTML = 'Show';
        }
    })
  }
```

Here's the codepen link as well in case you want to see the full code: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Yarome/pen/ZEWQgMM)

The problem is that when I click a button in one of the cards, the others also extend in size, like they're also showing the answer. The button only affects his immediate div parent, but seems like there's some problem affecting the other cards' divs at the same time.

I assume it's not a JS or HTML problem but a CSS problem, since the container has the 'flex' property and the others adapt their height to the first one. In fact, I tried resizing the screen and it only affects the first row of cards, not the second. I'm not sure how to work around this problem without having to create a class that affects the card that's being clicked and keeps the others card as non-clicked at the moment. I'm still just a tadpole but I want to keep the code as simple and clean as possible, and keeping it Javascript only (I guess there are ways to fix this with Jquery but since this is only a JS exercise I wanted to solve it with that).

It's my first post here, so feel free to add suggestions to improve or fix anything in my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `align-items: flex-start` in your `.container` class.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start; // Add this line
}
```